# What is the best way to pass information from a C# app to a C++ app while both are running?

Tags: c#, c++, ipc

What would be the best way to pass information from a windows forms C# app to a MFC C++ app while they are running?  I don't need to send much, just a small string.

Thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 4):

Going down the list of IPC options:

- Memory mapped files.  Easy in C++, tough in C# without pointers, awkward handshaking
- WM_COPYDATA.  Easy in both, tricky to find the window handle you'll need
- Clipboard.  Easy in both, very awkward handshaking
- COM.  Out-of-proc is a beast, forget about it
- Mailslots.  Not suitable for one-to-one communication
- Pipes.  Easy in .NET 3.5, do-able in C++ but a bit tricky to get right
- Sockets.  Easy in both, hard to pass up.

Answer (score 3):

Use named pipes, see this [posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46693/-net-3-5-most-secure-way-to-pass-string-between-processes).

Comment: Named pipes are INSANELY fast on the local system.  Specificially designed for IPC.

Answer (score 0):

If the C++ app has a main window, take a look at using the SendMessage function (via P/Invoke) in the C# app to send a WM_COPYDATA message to the C++ app.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649011%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

MailSlot api is small and simple but requires P/Invoke to use from c# and can go outside your local machine so needs care.
see my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517376/c-queue-or-servicebus-with-no-dependencies/546328#546328)

Named pipes may well be more robust but this is an alternate.